# Close vote reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, vote-to-close, close-reasons

When voting to close a question, you can add a custom reason, or use one of these:

- Questions seeking price-shopping assistance are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.
- Questions on driving techniques are off-topic unless asked in regard to a specific mechanical problem. See: Are driving questions on-topic?
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Could we add more for common things - particularly this one (or something similar):

- Questions relating to local laws are off topic because they are only relevant to a single jurisdiction and do not relate to solving mechanical problems

Comment: While I see the gist of your question, how often do we actually get a question which involves law? At a SWAG, I'd bet it's less than once per month? Does that meet a threshold for having a separate selection? And don't get me wrong, I'm not against this! Just throwing that out there.

Comment: Could we use one for low-quality questions that are unlikely to ever receive an answer (because of the question or a low rep user that may not come back)?

Comment: @Paulster: There are five slots available per site. While you're right that a specific reason might be needed rarely in absolute terms, it might also make sense to have the most clear-cut reasons spelled out in the system. In some cases, having a more official-looking message can be helpful to someone whose question is closed. As an aside, you and other 10k users can see stats on the custom close reasons at http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats

Comment: So, looking at the close vote reasons on that link, we have in the last 90 days, 25 custom off-topic closures - 7 are law-related, 5 recommending other sites (EE and Bicycles - the 4 suggesting EE look like wrongly-migrated questions originally from there), 2 chat, 1 language, 2 opinion-based, 1 software, and the rest are unclear from the comments

Comment: Over the same time period there were 16 price-shopping and one driving techniques questions

Comment: I take it @BobCross either hasn't seen this or is ignoring it?